# Application without support for older IPhones

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image, app-store

I'm developing some app that it is not actually on iphones older than 4. So I have included in the project only @2x images, and have seted not to launch on iphone 3x and older. Is it ok not  to include images without @2x suffix, cause it is not relevant? (I mean for AppStore)

Comment: Probably not ok.  Have you tested it on an iPad?  I believe Apple requires iPhone apps to work on iPads (in the iPad's compatibility mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The low res images are not required. Don't forget that the iPad can also run your iPhone app, and would be using non-retina images.

Comment: See this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229795/is-a-copy-of-a-high-res-and-standard-res-required-for-iphone

Answer (score 0):

For memory purposes the OS uses the low-res pictures in older iPhones/iPods that's why it would need them. So if you are not supporting them you probably don't need them, I would recommend you to not add the suffix (just in case it messes up with something), just leave the original name of the image.

About supporting your app in the iPad, in the 2x mode your app will look a bit better because it will be using the high-res pictures instead of the low-res pictures.